# Bash: integer expression expected

Tags: bash

This recently stopped working. Any idea if I need to change anything in code?

```
TIME=`grep real < /tmp/EV_Check.time | cut -d ' ' -f2`
time=$TIME
test $time -ge $ct
result=$?
        if [ "$result" -eq "1" ]
        then
        crit=1
        msg="Report execution takes $time!"
        fi
test $time -ge $wt
result=$?
        if [ "$result" -eq "1" ]
        then
        warn=1
        msg="Report execution takes $time!"
        fi

if [ $crit -eq 1 -a $warn -eq 0 ]
then
       echo "Critical value must be greater than warning value !"
       help_usage
       exit 3
fi
```

I am getting the below error:-

```
./check_ev_report.sh: line 158: test: 0.45: integer expression expected
./check_ev_report.sh: line 166: test: 0.45: integer expression expected
OK - 0.45
```

Comment: Always quote your variables.  Start there.

Comment: I suspect that your file `/tmp/EV_Check.time` contains the output of `time`. Bash arithmetic, including `-ge`, works on **integers** only. Decimal points are not allowed, much less strings like `9m50.017s`.

Comment: `test` and `[` are the same command!

Comment: That's not the script that produces that output.  One giveaway is the `OK`.  Another is that you have errors on lines 158 and 166 of a 23-line script.

Comment: It helps if you make a *minimal reproducible example.*  As @JdeBP pointed out, it's obvious that you didn't do that.  :)

Answer (score 4):

bash can only do integer arithmetic.

If you want to compare floating point values, you'll have to call out to an external tool such as `bc`

```
if [[ $(bc <<<"$time >= $ct") == "1" ]]; then
    do_something
fi
```